# Mapping TIMESTAMP column from PostgreSQL to LocalDate

Tags: java, hibernate, timestamp, localdate

I have field in Entity:

```
@Column(name = "BILL_DATE")
private LocalDate billDate;
```

And my system work with `oracle` and `posthresql`. In posgresql this columt has type `timestamp` but in oracle - `date`. When I try start server with `postgeSQL` I get error:

```
wrong column type encountered in column [bill_date] in table [charges]; found [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)], but expecting [date (Types#DATE)]
```

if I add annotation `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` I get another error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property
```

But I do not want use `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`. **How to solve this problem?**

Comment: which hibernate version?

Comment: @Jerry06 `[org.hibernate.Version] [] HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}`

Comment: it should work, maybe problem with your hibernate configuration

Comment: what about Long? It will wrap both Date and TimeStamp types, but you will get epoch timestamp of format: 1540802067000

Answer (score 9):

Both [Date in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413) and [Timestamp in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) store date **and** time. Indeed according to [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) you should map them either to [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) if the timestamp is w/o the timezone, or to [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) if it's with the timezone.

Hibernate 5 should support Java8 Time API, anyway if you're using JPA, you could implement AttributeConverter

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter < LocalDate, Timestamp > {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate attribute) {
        return attribute != null ? Timestamp.valueOf(attribute.atStartOfDay()) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp dbData) {
        return dbData != null ? dbData.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate() : null;
    }

}
```

Then you can use

```
@Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
@Column(name = "BILL_DATE")
private LocalDate billDate;
```

Comment: I can use `LocalDateTime ` without converter. It is work. I need store date as date in timestamp column

Comment: @ip696 "Valid input for the time stamp types consists of the concatenation of a date and a time" so a timestamp column will always have hh:mm:ss too. If you have to use LocalDate, you could try using a converter. Of course if you use LocalDateTime you can easily convert it to LocalDate